# How do I create a Package.swift file for a package in Xcode's package manager?

Tags: swift, xcode, swifty-json

I'm trying to use SwiftyJSON within an Xcode project via the built in package manager. The first time I try to add it through Xcode, The app complains about missing Swift-tools version specification like so: [image]

After clicking "Add Anyway" the package came in, but it appears grayed out and doesn't have the usual hierarchy:

[image]

After removing it and adding it again, the package apppears like normal. But I get "cannot find in scope" errors when I try to import it using `import`.
[image]

SwiftyJSON's [documentation](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#integration) states there's an extra step involving making changes to Package.swift. But I have no idea which one they are talking about. I tried to change the one in the package dependencies section, but it won't let me make any changes to the file.

Where am I supposed to put the code needed? I really don't want to use Cocoapods or Carthage because I like specifically how Xcode's package manager lets you import packages directly from GitHub in a couple of clicks without needing to switch over to the terminal.

Comment: SPM is awesome. I highly suggest people stop using Carthage or Cocoapods and use SPM. So good on you for trying. Though I don't understand why not use Apple's Decodable? protocol. Still if you want to use SwiftyJSON. I did notice that when adding it, it first tried to add version 3.0.0. That version doesn't support SPM but its also very much outdated. Version 5.0.0 (latest) does. And then it installs just fine.

Comment: By the way, the manifest file warning you are seeing is there because the version you are trying to install is probably missing a line like `// swift-tools-version:5.0` in its `Package.swift` file. They did finally added this in Apr 2, 2019. So it looks like version 5.0.0 of SwiftyJSON is the only version that has it. It took them over 2 years to add it. Honestly I wouldn't trust a package with such crappy maintainability. I don't suggest that you use it.